# How to go from chat to private discussion?

Tags: support, chat

If two people are having a conversation in chat and wish to jump to a private discussion (e.g. because they wish to discuss stuff outside the Astronomy Stack Exchange guidelines or because they are discussing sensitive, restricted, confidential or private information) then how could they do this?

I am thinking about solutions that might be:-
(a) Either within the site or by going "off-site"
(b) Either with continued anonymity or with revealing identities.

Answer (score 6):

If the conversation is literally "sensitive, restricted, confidential or private information", then off-site is really your only option (i.e. everything we do is designed to be public, by design).

But if your goal is simply to create a quieter, one-on-one environment for a more-focused conversation with a specific user (away from the mainstay of the room), you can click the user you wish to speak to and select **'start a new room with this user'**.

That feature does ***not*** create a private chat room (fully visible, Google indexed, etc), but it can be a useful way to pull someone aside "into the hall" where you can discuss an issue one-on-one without interfering with the conversation flow of a much larger room.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that helps.  I still would like to know if there is a simple method of meeting up off-site that does not require public disclosure of email addresses. I dont expect such a method to be provided by Stack Exchange.